# Laravel Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a basic application which stores expenses in a table containing the following columns:

- `id`
- `user_id`
- `quote_id` (nullable)
- `title`
- `type`
- `net`

The `quote_id` column is linked to my `quotes` table; however, there can also be entries in the table without a `quote_id`.

I'm trying to output all expenses by using the relationship `expenses()` on my `user` model.

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->expenses as $e)
    {{ $e->id }}
    {{ $e->net }}
    {{ $e->quote->title }}
    {{ $e->quote_id }}
@endforeach
```

On my `expenses` model, I also have a relationship between the `expense` and the `quote`.

```
public function quote()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Quote', 'id','quote_id');
}
```

This is great for when there is always a `quote_id` in the table however some entries don't have a `quote_id` and I get the following error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Run a `dd($e->quote)` and see what it returns; betcha it isn't a single `quote` object. In fact I can say for sure that it is not, since the relationship is **`hasMany`**

Comment: @TimLewis I've updated to a belongs to but now I get can not find object which is expected.. How do I output even if no has one is found on quote_id?

Comment: `{{ $e->quote ? $e->quote->title : "N/A" }}` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell (from your DB structure), each `expense` only has one `quote` not many. In other words, first order of business would be changing your `$expense->quote()` function to:

```
public function quote()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Quote', 'id', 'quote_id');

    // Since your column naming is standard, this should work too:
    // return $this->hasOne('App\Quote');
}
```

Then, since `quote_id` can be `null`, you still need to check that the `expense`'s `quote()` is an object. Something like this can be used in your Blade template:

```
@if($e->quote)
    {{ $e->quote->title }}
    {{ $e->quote_id }}
@endif
```

---

If you continue to use `hasMany()` instead of `hasOne()` (for whatever reason), then `quote()` will return an `array` of `quote` objects that you can loop through.

```
@foreach($e->quote as $q)
    {{ $q->title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the quote->title in an if condition that checks if the quote exists.

If the quote for the expense is null(ie doesn't exist), then it can't have a title!

And also change your relationship to belongsTo. A quote has many expenses, and an expense belongs to a single quote if I understand correctly